# Finding solutions set of such equations in $\mathbb Z$, $\mathbb R$ etc

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Kindly solve for obtaining  solutions of the following equations in $\mathbb Z$, $\mathbb R$ etc

1) Solve in $\mathbb Z$ for $\frac{3}{\sqrt{x}} + \frac{2}{\sqrt{y}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$

2) For M = { $(a-b)^2$ + $b^2$|a, b in $\mathbb Z$}. Prove that $2012$ not in $M$. Also prove that, 
     $M$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb N$ in respect of the multiplication of integers.

3) Solve in $\mathbb R$ for $5$$x^3$$ - 18$$x^2$$ + 43x - 6 = 12($$2^x$$)$

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

We give rather full information towards 2), and much less full information towards 1). Question 3), which mixes polynomial and exponential, has less structure.  If you are looking for non-negative *integer* solutions $x$, you can just compute, trying $x=0$, $1$, $2$, and so on. You will find some solutions. And if you go far enough in your computations, you can *prove* that you got them all, by showing that after the numbers you have tested, $(12)2^x$ is bigger than the left-hand side.

For closure, note the following famous identity, which can be verified by expanding each side.
$$(s^2+t^2)(u^2+v^2)=(su+tv)^2+(sv-tu)^2.$$

We show that $2012$ is not a sum of two squares, so in particular is not of the form described. The number $2012$ is equal to $4(503)$. It is easy to verify that **if** this is a sum of $2$ squares, say $2012=x^2+y^2$, then $x$ and $y$ must be even. So $503$ would be a sum of $2$ squares. We show that cannot happen.

There are very few candidate squares, so we could go through them all, and check that none of them work.  Or else note that $503$ is congruent to $-1$ modulo $4$. It is easy to verify that a sum of $2$ squares cannot be congruent to $-1$ modulo $4$. For the square of an odd number is congruent to $1$ modulo $4$, indeed modulo $8$.

For a), there are two things to do, one of which takes a fair bit of work. It is plausible, and *should be proved*, that our numbers $x$ and $y$ are of the form $2a^2$ and $2b^2$ respectively.

Assuming that, we are looking for positive integers $a$ and $b$ such that $\frac{3}{a}+ \frac{2}{b}=1$. A quick search will find them all, since $a$ and $b$ cannot both be big. Alternately, rewrite the equation as $ab-2a-3b=0$, and either solve for $a$, or rewrite as $(a-3)(b-2)=6$.

The part about proving that solutions $x$ and $y$ must be of the shape we have described is a somewhat complicated variant of the proof that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational. As a start, note that by squaring both sides we can conclude that $xy$ is a perfect square,

Comment: Nicolas! excellent explanation you made. If you can break all my parts separately, then it is quite good by answering 1 and 2 parts of my post.

Comment: "So $503$ is a sum of $2$ squares." $503$ is a prime and it's congruent to $3$ modulo $4$. You're going to have [problems solving](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_theorem_on_sums_of_two_squares) $x^2 + y^2 = 503$ over the integers.

Comment: Indeed. And the post explains why there will be problems. Note that we started with "**if** (emphasis added) $2012$ is a sum of $2$ squares."

Comment: Right. Man, those small words can be so easy to miss!

Comment: @kahen: Thanks for pointing out that the wording could lead to confusion. I have added a number of words, which I hope are enough.